# Histogram and probability curve for a range of values

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, charts, histograms

I don't know if I will be clear about what I am asking for, but here is my problem: how could I create a histogram (with the probability curve, later) when I have many different values (each one with frequency equals to one), in such a way that in the $x$ axis I put ranges (like: $0$ to $80$, $80$ to $160$, $160$ to $240$ and so on) and on the $y$ axis I have the frequency, that is the number of values that lie within the $x$ range?

To say, the list of my values is:

$200,540,563,1031,458,957,200,800,226,314,517,210,900,160,432,380,89,1300,850,120,350,222,243,600,300,173,549,80,500,162,500,450,2000,300,647,371$

I know I have to use BarChart. I just cannot get how to create a range on the $x$ axis and the frequency over $y$ axis.

Thank you!

Comment: `Histogram[data, {80}]` where `data` is the list of values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get into the 21st century and use nonparametric density estimates.  In other words, dump the histogram.

```
data = {200, 540, 563, 1031, 458, 957, 200, 800, 226, 314, 517, 210, 
   900, 160, 432, 380, 89, 1300, 850, 120, 350, 222, 243, 600, 300, 
   173, 549, 80, 500, 162, 500, 450, 2000, 300, 647, 371};
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, "LeastSquaresCrossValidation",
  {"Bounded", {0, \[Infinity]}, "Gaussian"}];
Plot[PDF[skd, x], {x, 0, Max[data]}]
```

[image: PDF]

And get the CDF:

```
Plot[CDF[skd, x], {x, 0, Max[data]}]
```

[image: CDF]

Comment: Wondrous!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {200, 540, 563, 1031, 458, 957, 200, 800, 226, 314, 517, 210, 
   900, 160, 432, 380, 89, 1300, 850, 120, 350, 222, 243, 600, 300, 
   173, 549, 80, 500, 162, 500, 450, 2000, 300, 647, 371};
bins = Table[80 i, {i, 0, Max[data]/80 + 1}]


Histogram[data, {bins}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[data, {bins}, "Probability"]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! How to add the probability curve?

Comment: Since the bins are of equal width `Histogram[data, {80}]` is sufficient.

Comment: @xyzt You can count probabilities and these should sum up to one. `probs = BinCounts[data, {bins}]/Length@data // N` and `Total@probs`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I was trying a new syntax variation for *bspec*. Thanks for the heads up.